# Objective C Converting float to integer produces strange results

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have float which has value 30 which I get from core data.

When I print the value using NSLog I get 30.

```
NSLog(@"The value of float temp is %@", [self.detailItem valueForKey:@"credit"]);
```

When I print value by casting float to int I get strange numbers and different result each time log is printed:

```
NSLog(@"The value of float temp is %d", (int)[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"credit"]);

137978864
122273424
```

Comment: Well, you can't cast a `float` to an `int`

Comment: @Undo you can cast `float` to `int`, what you can't do is cast `id`/`NSNumber *` to `int`

Comment: @xlc Actually, it looks like you can't cast an `NSNumber` to `int`, now that I look at it closer.

Comment: What you are *actually* seeing is the memory address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
NSLog(@"The value of float temp is %d", [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"credit"] intValue]);
```

Comment: Thanks, simple solution. I need more coffee

Answer (score 1):

valueForKey returns an object. Coredata stores objects such as NSNumber and NSString. You cast those by using intValue. Try:

`NSLog(@"The value of float temp is %d", [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"credit"] intValue]);`

Comment: `intValue` in _not_ a cast, it is a method that is called on an `NSNumber` instance.